# Prove that angles $\angle ADB$ and $\angle ACB$ in a convex quadrilateral $ABCD$ are obtuse.

Tags: geometry

In a convex quadrilateral $ABCD$ distance between midpoints of $AB$ and $DC$ is less than distance between midpoints of $AC$ and $BD$. Prove that angles $\angle ADB$ and $\angle ACB$ are obtuse.

I have tried to use vectors to get $$|\frac{1}{2}(\vec{AD} + \vec{BC})| < |\frac{1}{2}(\vec{AB} + \vec{CD})|$$
I don't know how to continue though. Hope one of you can help me! Thank you.
[image]

Comment: This is false. Note that if we rename $A\to D$, $B\to C$, $C\to B$, $D\to A$ then we don't change the assumptions but the thesis becomes false.